# Accessing an object's methods while using List Iterator

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator

My objective is to iterate over a list of objects, and have the two functionalities:
- be able to remove from the list during iteration.
- be able to access the public get methods of the objects I'm iterating over, to be able to determine whether or not they should be removed.

For example, how would I get the following to work? Currently it gives the exception `java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to random.folder.dir.TestClass`.

```
public class TestClass {
    public int foo;

    public TestClass(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }       
}




List<TestClass> testList = new ArrayList<TestClass>();
testList.add(new TestClass(1));
testList.add(new TestClass(2));
testList.add(new TestClass(3));

Iterator<TestClass> it = tickScratch.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(((TestClass)it).getFoo() == 2)
        it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` is a `ListIterator<TestClass>` instance, hence it doesn't have the `getFoo()` method.

You should use `next()` to fetch the next element and then remove it if needed:

```
while (it.hasNext() {
  TestClass current = it.next(); 

  if (current.getFoo() == 2)
    it.remove();
}
```

Comment: Does this work if I want to change the internal state of the object inside the list while in the loop (through setter methods)?

Answer (score 1):

Need change

```
  if(((TestClass)it).getFoo() == 2)
```

to

```
    if(it.getNext().getFoo() == 2)
```

Comment: you can't call getFoo() on an Iterator

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code here:

```
Iterator<TestClass> it = tickScratch.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(((TestClass)it).getFoo() == 2)
        it.remove();
}
```

`it` is an `Iterator<TestClass>` not a `TestClass`, therefore you are getting an error that `$Itr cannot be cast to random.folder.dir.TestClass`. What you are doing is similar to casting an `ArrayList<String>` to a `String`, you have a bunch of `TestClass` objects, not just one.

Use an iterator like this:

```
Iterator<TestClass> it = tickScratch.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next().getFoo() == 2)
        it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `next ()` funcion returns the object 'pointed to' by the iterator. Use it as you wish.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()